# How can I evaluate: $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I need to calculate

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$$

I know it's $-1$, but I can't figure out the steps. It gives me $+1$ when I turn it into

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^2/x^2}}$$

So how do I do this?

Edit: z is constant

Comment: Is $z$ fixed or a constant?

Comment: $x < 0$. so $\sqrt{x^2 + z^2} \ne x \sqrt{1+\frac{z^2}{x^2}}$.  Instead $\sqrt{x^2 + z^2} = -x \sqrt{1+ \frac {z^2}{x^2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a classic mistake.

**Disclaimer**: This answer only works in the assumption that $z$ does not depend on $x$

Let me write in detail what's happening:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x² + z²}} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x²(1 + z²/x²)}} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1 + z²/x²}}$$

and for negative $x$ (you are taking the limit to negative infinity), we have $|x| = -x$

Hence,

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x² + z²}} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{-x\sqrt{1 + z²/x²}} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 + z²/x²}} = -1$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+z^{2}}} = \frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1+z^{2}/x^{2}}} = -1 + \frac{z^{2}}{2x^{2}}+o(\frac{1}{x^{2}}) \to -1$

Answer (score 1):

note that we get
$$\frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^2}}$$